# Python Why can my list only recognize one set of login details?

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary, while-loop, append

I tried making a login detail storing program that stores usernames and passwords. I managed to make it work partially where the login manages to recognise the 1st set of login details, however, my login() function cannot seem to recognise the 2nd set of login details that has been appended to the list. Basically, if I append some passwords to the vault list e.g "qwerty", "123456", "2017", it will only accept the 1st password and not the 2nd or 3rd. How do I get the program to accept more login details, not only just one set? Any help would be appreciated.

```
vault = []
appvault = []
passvault = []

def menu(): 
    mode = input("""Hello {}, below are the modes that you can choose from:\n
    ##########################################################################
    a) Login with username and password
    b) Register as a new user
    To select a mode, enter the corresponding letter of the mode below
    ##########################################################################\n
    > """).strip()
    return mode

def login():
    if len(vault) > 0 : #user has to append usernames and passwords before it asks for login details
        print("Welcome to the login console")
        while True:
            username = input ("Enter Username: ") 
            if username == "":
                print("User Name Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            password = input ("Enter Password: ") 
            if password == "":
                print("Password Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            try:
                for i in vault: 
                    if i[username] == password:
                        print("Username matches!")
                        print("Password matches!")
                        logged() #jumps to logged function and tells the user they are logged on
                        break 
            except KeyError: #the except keyerror recognises the existence of the username and password in the list
                print("The entered username or password is not found!")

    else:
        print("You have no usernames and passwords stored!")

def register(): #example where the username is appended. Same applies for the password
    print("Please create a username and password into the password vault.\n")

    while True:
        validname = True
        while validname:
            username = input("Please enter a username you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your username must be at least 3 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not username.isalnum():
                print("Your username cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(username) < 3:
                print("Your username must be at least 3 characters long \n")
            elif len(username) > 30:
                print("Your username cannot be over 30 characters \n")
            else:
                validname = False 
        validpass = True

        while validpass:
            password = input("Please enter a password you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your password must be at least 8 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not password.isalnum():
                print("Your password cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(password) < 8:
                print("Your password must be at least 8 characters long \n")
            elif len(password) > 20:
                print("Your password cannot be over 20 characters long \n")
            else:
                validpass = False #The validpass has to be True to stay in the function, otherwise if it is false, it will execute another action, in this case the password is appended.
        vault.append({username:password})
        validinput = True
        while validinput:
            exit = input("\nEnter 'end' to exit or any key to continue to add more username and passwords:\n> ")
            if exit in ["end", "End", "END"]:
                break
            else:
                validinput = False
                register()
        return register

def logged():
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
    print("You are logged on.")

while True:
        chosen_option = menu() #a custom variable is created that puts the menu function into the while loop

        if chosen_option in ["a", "A"]:
            login()

        if chosen_option in ["b", "B"]:
            register()

        else:
            print("""That was not a valid option, please try again:\n """)
```

Comment: Why are you using a `list` of `dict`s? The problem is that you get catch a `KeyError` and continue *outside the loop*, because every time you try to check the second or third set of login-details, it fails on the first iteration `if i[username] == password:` Why don't you just keep a `dict` of login-details?

Comment: Or, at the very least, wrap that line in the `try-except`, not the whole for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through a `list` of `dicts`. Change `vault` to a `dict`, and get rid of the for loop:

```py
vault = {}

def login():
    if len(vault) > 0 : #user has to append usernames and passwords before it asks for login details
        print("Welcome to the login console")
        while True:
            username = input ("Enter Username: ") 
            if username == "":
                print("User Name Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            password = input ("Enter Password: ") 
            if password == "":
                print("Password Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            try:
                if vault[username] == password:
                    print("Username matches!")
                    print("Password matches!")
                    logged() #jumps to logged function and tells the user they are logged on
                    break 
            except KeyError: #the except keyerror recognises the existence of the username and password in the list
                print("The entered username or password is not found!")

    else:
        print("You have no usernames and passwords stored!")
```

And you will have to replace the append in `register()` from

```py
vault.append({username:password})
```

to

```py
vault[username] = password
```

On another note, I would suggest not to store the actual passwords, but rather the hashes. Take a look [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/python-tutorials/securely-hash-passwords-in-python/).